# Changing the Permalink Structure without Resetting the Facebook Like Counts?

Tags: facebook

When changing the permalink structure of a blog, Facebook and Twitter will treat the articles with new URLs as brand new articles and will reset that Tweet/Like counters.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not possible. FB and twitter is counting the actual URL, nothing related to WP in specific. even adding or removing the www from the URL will cause the numbers to reset.

FWIW, changing it back will bring back whatever numbers were there before.

Comment: Yes. They call them "permalinks" for a reason. They're supposed to be permanent. Choose wisely the first time.